# JavaScript: Swipe for Action Pattern Implementation

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented the [Swipe for Action](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/swipe-for-action) Android pattern in my mobile web application (PhoneGap) using JavaScript & CSS animations/transitions.

[image: Swipe for Action Pattern]

However, there's one thing that's still eluding me.

I wish, that once the action menu is displayed fully and the user clicks anywhere outside of the action menu (labelled 3 in the figure), the menu should retract and the original item displayed (labelled 1 in the figure).

In a desktop application, one could "capture focus" and perform the transition back to (1) in `lostfocus`.

What is the JS equivalent of `lostfocus` event. I see an `onfocus` and `onblur` event, but from what I read it's really meant for things that need focus; like input, textarea, etc.

How else could I catch that event I'm interested in, other than putting some code in the `touchend` of every other element in the page and forcing the retraction of open actions  explicitly?

Comment: You don’t need to put the touchend on every element of the page; it should be enough to register the event on the body during the capturing phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you gave the answer yourself. `focus` and `blur` are the events to be used for this and they are *not* exclusively meant for input elements, as you can see here [1].
I'm even trigger the `focus` event manually in a layer use case: A layer opens and I want to capture the keypress of `ESC` to close the layer. For this I need to set the focus on the layer as my event handler would not fire otherwise.

To capture the click outside you just need to register for `pointerUp` or `click` events on an element that spans the whole screen (it must really cover the whole screen like the `body` element). Because of the event bubbling the handler will fire as long as nothing else captured and cancelled it.

[1] https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dom3events/raw-file/tip/html/DOM3-Events.html#event-type-blur