# Catch All Action Handler

Tags: ember.js

Now, this is really a question that's evolved from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981068/ember-component-block-form-more-than-one-outlet-yield). There is a whole lot more info there, but I guess, it's better to ask a direct specific question. So here it goes:

We typically define actions in a controller like so:

```
var FooController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        login: function() {
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to define a catch all action handler, like so (hypothetically):

```
actions: {
    login: function() {
    },
    *: function(actionName, paramArray) {
    }
}
```

This would be analogous to embers [catch all route](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1465) which I believe has been implemented, though I haven't tried it.

I need this because my `Ember.Component` renders a user supplied [partial template](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper) using the `{{partial}}` helper. This partial might have `{{action}}`'s specified in them. These actions don't bubble up to the calling controller or route and are lost inside the component. This fact is mentioned in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/) in para 4.

If a catch all action was possible, my component could implement it and send the action back to the caller using something like this:

```
actions: {
    *: function(actionName, paramArray) {
        this.sendAction(actionName, paramArray)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality around the `actions` hash on controllers, views and routes is provided by the action handler mixin [1]. As you can see, it injects the `send(actionName)` method and makes enables an object to receive actions. You can now easily override this function and catch all actions instead of looking for it in the `actions` hash -- which is what the implementation does.

[1] https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/action_handler.js#L8