# When do you use yield in components?

Tags: ember.js

I'm curious as to how other devs use `{{yield}}` in components. In my case, I rarely use it. I just usually pass what I would like to `{{yield}}` into an attribute. I only use `{{yield}}` when I want the component to act like a *web component* (which doesn't happen very much).

Any of you guys have like a rule/best practice on when to use `{{yield}}`?

Comment: this is also a tangentially useful / relevant answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30107261/1396904

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `{{yield}}` if you don't feel any need for it. :)

The benefits of using `{{yield}}` are:

1. You can pass Handlebars-generated HTML, not just a string.
2. Thus, you can use Ember components.
3. The context of the passed block belongs to the parent, not to the component that yields. It's super handy.

The natural use for `{{yield}}` is to decorate a template block with some HTML.

Note that, using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107261/901944), you can pass multiple blocks into a component and yield them in different parts of the component's HTML.

Comment: Hah! I never knew that we could do multiple yields. I guess that makes it more useful that I thought. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use yield if you want to use your components in a block form with dynamic content.
This is usually useful for example to wrap a area multiple times the same way.

A good example is a input wrapper, that provides some tags and css fun, as well as showing the label, but you yield where you want to put an `{{input}}` or an `<select>`